# Preventing users from using Data Import Wizard

Tags: data-import-wizard

Is there a way to keep users from uploading their data using the Data Import Wizard? I just had a user ask me if they could do that, but I would really like to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [covered in depth in this article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.faq_import_general_permissions.htm&type=5)

You would need to check the users' Profiles and Permission Sets to ensure that the relevant permission is not included.

For example,

- to import leads, ensure the `Import Leads` permission is not granted
- to import custom objects, ensure the `Import Custom Objects` permission is not granted